# Custom Action based on Visualforce for mobile and desktop

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, publisher

I created VF page for custom action to be added to Publisher.

This VF page is used in both mobile and desktop versions.
In mobile Submit button is added automatically.

How should 'Submit' button be added to desktop version?
Is it possible to rename Submit label of this button to value like 'Close'?

Comment: Share your code please?

Comment: Any luck finding out answer to this question?